# Multivendor based on price

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor

I am using Marketplace in my Website. In individual page i display seller name (soled by)

If More then one seller available in particular product it will display it will display all seller in down

so i need if which seller having low price that seller should come first

```
<div class="block-title"><strong><span>
                        <?php   if($rowsocial['shoptitle']!='')
                                echo $rowsocial['shoptitle'];
                            else
                                echo  $rowsocial['profileurl']; ?>
                        </span></strong>
                    </div>
```

[For more check this](http://kidsdial.com/toysbox-pretty-flowers-sr.html)

this code display seller list

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form1" class="ma">
                        <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $currentUrl =  Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId(); ?>" name="mpassignproduct_id" class="mpassignproduct_id"/>

                         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>

                        <div class="seller">
                            <!-- <div style="clear: both; margin-top: 10px;"></div> -->
                            <span class="data profile">
                                <div class="wk_seller_profile">
                                    <?php if(strlen($logo)<=0): ?>
                                        <!-- <a href="<?php //echo  Mage::getUrl()."marketplace/seller/profile/".$profileurl ?>"><?php //echo $profileurl; ?></a> -->
                                        <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl()."marketplace/seller/collection/".$profileurl ?>"><?php echo $profileurl; ?></a>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl()."marketplace/seller/collection/".$profileurl ?>" title="Visit Profile">
                                            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'avatar/'.$logo;?>" />
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div class="seller_rating">
                                    <?php
                                        $rating=Mage::getModel('marketplace/feedback')->getTotal($seller->getSellerId());
                                        if($rating['totalfeed']>0) {?>
                                            <div class="ratingslider-box">
                                                <div style="width:<?php echo $rating['totalfeed']?>%;" class="rating"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="review_count">
                                                <?php echo $rating['totalfeed'].' %'?> <?php  echo " (".$rating['feedcount']." ".$this->__('Reviews').")"; ?>
                                            </span>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <div class="no-rating">
                                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/seller/feedback').$profileurl?>">
                                                    <?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this seller');?>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div> -->
                                <div class="seller_content">
                                    <ul>
                                    <div class="Delivery_hover_details">?
                                        <span class="coupontooltip">
                                            <div class="delivery_content">
                                              <h5>How do I place a Cash on Delivery (COD) order?</h5>
                                                <p>All items that have the "Cash on Delivery Available" icon are valid for order by Cash on Delivery.</p>
                                                <p>Add the item(s) to your cart and proceed to checkout.When prompted to choose a payment option, select "Cash on Delivery". </p>
                                                <p>Once you place the order you will receive confirmation call from our customer support for validation with in 48 hours. Once verified and confirmed, your order will be processed for shipment in the time specified, from the date of confirmation. You will be required to make a cash-only payment to our courier partner at the time of delivery of your order to complete the payment.</p>
                                                <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
                                                <p>The maximum order value for COD is ₹5000.</p>
                                                <p>e-Gift Vouchers or Store Credit cannot be used for COD orders.</p>
                                                <p>Cash-only payment at the time of delivery.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <li>Cash on Delivery may be available!</li>


                                    <div class="Delivery_hover_details">?
                                        <span class="coupontooltip">

                                       <h5> How do I return an item purchased on Totaltoys.com</h5>
                                        <p>Conveniently, you can call us at 092-434-22233 and email us at contact@totaltoys.com with order number, invoice number and product name. If you've received an item in a 'Damaged', 'Defective' or 'Not as Described' state.</p>

                                        <h5>Return & Replacement policy:</h5>
                                            <p>Returns or replacement request should be placed within 7 days from the date of delivery.</p>
                                            <p>As we receive your request, our concerned team will contact you to validate the compliant. The validation process may require submitting of product photos. Once the validation process is completed then further action will be taken.
                                            Once the product reaches to us/seller, the replacement will be proceed in 1-2 working days after physical inspection of the goods and shipment will be done simultaneously.</p>
                                            <p>If you've received an item in a 'Damaged', 'Defective' or 'Not as Described' state, all replacements/pickups will be done free of cost.</p>
                                            <p>If the packaging is tampered with or damaged, before accepting delivery of the goods, please refuse to take delivery of the package, and call us on 092-434-22233 or mail us at contact@totaltoys.com , mentioning your order reference number. We shall make our best efforts to ensure that a replacement delivery is made to you at the earliest.</p>
                                            <p>In the rare circumstances where a pickup cannot be done, you can ship the product through any courier. You will be reimbursed the shipping charges against the original receipt.</p>
                                            <p>Replacement is subjected to availability of stock. In case a replacement is not available, the amount will be refunded to your account from which the purchase was made. (Amount includes shipping and gift wrapping charges)</p>

                                            <h5> Return Request is not Accepted If:</h5>

                                            <li>Return request is made outside the specified time period</li>

                                            <li>Missing of tags, labels, original packing, and invoice.</li>

                                            <li>Misused or Mishandle of the product from customer end.</li>

                                            <p>For all refunds we will refund the amount to same mode of payment as used during checkout. Refunds for cash on delivery will be made via online transfer of funds to the customers bank account.</p>
                                            <p>If the customer chooses to cancel the order before the product is shipped, he will be entitled to a 100% refund.
                                            Do I have to return the free gift when I return a product?</p>

                                            <p>Yes. The free gift is included as part of the item order and needs to be returned along with the originally delivered product</p>

                                            <p>Please contact us on   contact@totaltoys.com  or call us at 092-434-22233 for any doubts and concerns</p>



                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <li><?php //echo $seller->getreplacement() ?> days Replacement Guarantee!</li> -->

                                    <?php if(!empty($seller->getreplacement())):?>
                                        <li><?php echo $seller->getreplacement() ?> days Replacement Guarantee!</li>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                       <li>10 days Replacement Guarantee!</li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>

                                </div>
                                <div class="product_img">
                                    <?php
                                        $mediDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
                                        $imagesdir = $mediDir . '/mpassignproduct/' . $seller->getMpassignproductId() . '/';
                                        if(file_exists($imagesdir)) {
                                            foreach (new DirectoryIterator($imagesdir) as $fileInfo) {
                                                if($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->isDir()) {continue;}
                                                if($fileInfo->isFile()) {
                                            ?>  
                                                <img src='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'mpassignproduct/'.$seller->getMpassignproductId().'/'.$fileInfo; ?>' class='used_product_image'/>
                                        <?php  
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </span>
                            <span class="data comment">
                                <span >
                                    <!--<?php //echo $seller->getProductDescription() ?>-->

                                    <?php if(!empty($seller->getdeliverytime())):?>
                                        <li><span> Usually Delivered in </span> <?php echo $seller->getdeliverytime() ?> <span> business days. </span></li>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                       <li><span> Usually Delivered in 5-7 business days. </span></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>



                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="data price">
                                <?php if($seller->getProductType() == 'configurable'): ?>
                                    <span class="price default" ><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(0, true, false);?></span>
                                    <?php 
                                        $options = unserialize($seller->getConfigOptions()); 
                                        $price = 0;
                                        foreach ($options['products'] as $key => $value) {
                                            $str = array();
                                            foreach ($value['attributes']['super_attribute'] as $key => $int) {
                                                $str[] = $int;
                                            } ?>
                                                <span style="display:none" data-qty="<?php echo $value['qty'] ?>" data-combination="<?php echo implode(',', $str) ?>" class="price" ><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($value['price'], true, false);?></span>
                                            <?php 
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <span class="price" ><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($seller->getPrice(), true, false);?></span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </span>
                            <span class="data addto">
                            <?php if($seller->getProductType() != 'configurable'): ?>
                                <?php if($seller->getQty() > 0): ?>
                                    <!-- <label for="qty">Qty:</label>
                                    <input id="qty" class="input-text qty" type="text" title="Qty" name="qty"> -->
                                    <button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>" class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>" onclick="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>">
                                        <span>
                                            <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span>
                                        </span>

                                    </button>



                                    <div>
                                        <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
                                        <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
                                    </div>

                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock">
                                        <span>Out of stock</span>
                                    </p>
                                <?php endif; ?>


                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php 
                                    $options = unserialize($seller->getConfigOptions()); 
                                    $temp = array();
                                    foreach ($options['products'] as $key => $value) {
                                        if(isset($value['selected'])) {
                                            foreach ($value['attributes']['super_attribute'] as $key1 => $int) {
                                                if(!count($temp[$key1]))
                                                    $temp[$key1] = array();
                                                array_push($temp[$key1], $int);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    foreach ($temp as $key => $value): ?>
                                        <select class="attribute<?php echo $key ?>" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $key ?>]" style="display:none">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <?php foreach ($value as $int): ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $int ?>"></option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>     
                                        </select>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>

                                    <!-- <label for="qty">Qty:</label>
                                    <input id="qty" class="input-text qty" type="text" title="Qty" name="qty"> -->
                                    <button style="display:none;margin-top:3px" id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>" class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>" type="submit">
                                        <span>
                                            <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock" style="display:none">
                                        <span>Out of stock</span>
                                    </p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: need some more code..

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: this is seller profile page? and they are using catalog product for product?

Comment: this is displaying list of seller available, if product have more then one seller

Comment: individual page i used 1st part code

Comment: which database table related to seller and product?

Comment: product's are stored in marketplace_product and assign product's are stored in marketplace_assignproduct.

Comment: price field name??

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get lowest price

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
          $query="SELECT *
              FROM marketplace_assignproduct where mpassignproduct_id='".Mage::registry('current_product')->getId()."' order by price ASC";
          $alldata =$readconnection->fetchOne($query);
          echo $alldata[0]['price'];
```

Comment: where i have to use this

Comment: where you want to show the price..

Comment: it showing Call to a member function getMpassignproductId() on a non-object in

Comment: $seller->getMpassignproductId() ia using from ur code. pass the product id here.

Comment: But both are different different module it will work

Comment: without any problem just pass i there and see

Comment: how to pass product id over here

Comment: add this code  where you are displaying product price.

Comment: check this url http://kidsdial.com/toysbox-pretty-flowers-sr.html

Comment: Is this product page

Comment: yes this is product page

Comment: updated the answer kindly check it

Comment: it shows error: Call to a member function fetchOne() on a non-object in

Comment: update answer kindly check

Comment: No error but noting displayed check this http://kidsdial.com/toysbox-pretty-flowers-sr.html

Comment: `echo $query="SELECT *
              FROM marketplace_assignproduct where mpassignproduct_id='".Mage::registry('current_product')->getId()."' order by price ASC"; ` and run query directly in database did you get the value?

Comment: sorry i didn't got your answer

Comment: when you echo ur the query will display run that query in database

Comment: i need to run in database

Comment: check that it give the result or not?

Comment: php script will work in phpmyadmin

Comment: no simple echo query in product page and the output of query execute in phpmyadmin

Comment: it is only for check that record of that product is in your table

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet code,

$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
$query="SELECT *
FROM marketplace_assignproduct where mpassignproduct_id='".Mage::registry('current_product')->getId()."' order by price ASC";
$alldata =$readconnection->fetchOne($query);
echo $alldata[0]['price'];

Or refer to this page to build a [multi-vendor marketplace](https://www.softsuave.com/multi-vendor-marketplace-solution)